# checked and unchecked Checkbox with another Activiti's Listview

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I have List-View with Check-box. and Checked Items Stores in to another Array-list. which is set on another Layout. but while I am back to current activity and change the selection of Check box, Array List of another Activity not discards the previous selection. How to fix it?
Here is my code.

```
enno = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.titleTxt);
            enno.setText(arrStudentList.get(position).getEnno());
            enno.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                     Log.e("dr","hello11");

                selectedStudents.add(String.valueOf(arrStudentList.get(position).getEnno()));

                    Log.e("dr",String.valueOf(selectedStudents.size()));
                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(arrStudentList.get(position).getEnno()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

............................
............................
public void onClick(View v) {
    SparseBooleanArray checked = listView.getCheckedItemPositions();


    for (int i = 0; i < checked.size(); i++) {
        // Item position in adapter
        int position = checked.keyAt(i);
        // Add sport if it is checked i.e.) == TRUE!
        if (checked.valueAt(i))
           selectedStudents.add(String.valueOf(arrStudentList.get(position).getEnno()));
    }

    String[] outputStrArr = new String[selectedStudents.size()];
    Log.e("dr","hello14");
    Log.e("dr",String.valueOf(selectedStudents.size()));

    for (int i = 0; i < selectedStudents.size(); i++) {
        outputStrArr[i] = selectedStudents.get(i);
        Log.e("dr","hello15");
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
            ResultActivity.class);

    // Create a bundle object
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putStringArray("selectedStudents", outputStrArr);

    // Add the bundle to the intent.
    intent.putExtras(b);

    // start the ResultActivity
    startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you moved to other activity with the ArrayList just remove the previous data which was already there.
In ResultActivity.class, override onBackPressed method and write the code to remove all the data in the ArrayList.

```
   arrayList.remove(object);
```

So, if you come back and click on the button, the ArrayList with the new data will be displayed. Check this. Hope it will help you.

Comment: But I don't want to remove all data. suppose by mistake user checked one check-box and navigate to the ResultAvtivity.class. and to uncheck it he/she should come back to main activity and uncheck that check-box and again navigate to ResultActivity. and other selection should be same as it is.